# cakePHP - can i save ONLY the associated models data using save()?

Tags: cakephp, model, save, model-associations

Can I use the `$this->ModelName->AssociatedModel->save($this->data)` to save only the related data?

If not - what are my options?

The data structure is:

```
$this->data['AssociatedModel']['field_a'] = 'some value';
$this->data['AssociatedModel']['field_b'] = 'some other value';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can save associated data like that.

Comment: Well, i ask since i am trying to do so and it won't. there are no validation errors and no errors at all... just won't save (the sql log shows no attempt to do so)

Comment: Well, now it's working.. i assumed that there is no need to provide the $this->data parameter, thought it was implied by the mechanism.. i was wrong. thanks

Answer (score 1):

well, I landed here with a User HABTM ROLE usecase where the User table is a read-only db view.
The accepted solution didn't worked for me on cake2.x

In the end I settled on the following AppModel method:

```
public function saveHabtmOnly($data, $parent_id) {
    $this->_saveMulti($data, $parent_id, $db=$this->getDataSource());
    // _saveMulti has no failure signaling
    // probably just throws Exception
    return true;
}
```

where
$data = array('Role'=>array(...));
and $parent_id is the id of the User